# Scala: "val" as identifier possible? Linking to java library needs it

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

In my scala code, I'm using a java library which defines an object with a public attribute called "val":

```
public class XYZ {
    public int val=...
}
```

Is there a way to get this attribute in scala?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use backticks. They remove the reserved status of *any* Scala keyword (or symbol).

```
val foo = new XYZ
foo.`val`
```

See the [Scala Interoperability FAQ](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SYGN/Interoperability+FAQs).